# How to get queue and jndi names

Tags: queue, jms, websphere, jndi, pcf

I am trying to get a list of the queue names and jndi names in java. I have tried using pcf and have only been able to get queue names. The documentation on the IBM sight has not been too helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MQ Java PCF classes can be used to do a number of tasks like inquiring list of queues, channels etc. Also Add/Update/Delete number of queue manager objects can be done. But PCF classes can not be used inquiring JNDI names. JNDI names must be retrieved from a JNDI store like File/LDAP/J2EE JNDI and not in MQ queue manager.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Since your inquiry was tagged WebSphere, I'll assume some version of WebSphere Application Server (WAS).  WAS includes a utility called `dumpnamespace`.  Run it with the `-h` option to list its options.  Aim it at your bootstrap port and it should do as its name implies.